# How else can I write this nested query more efficiently?

Tags: sql, subquery

Is there a more efficient of writing this nested query (query had been drastically simplified but essentially fields need to build up from base tables all the way up to desired result).

@YearofBookingminus1 is a variable declared and calculated. This is passed through and not necessarily required for the question at hand. I have not added this code in.

```
SELECT fct.ContractNo,
       Paced_revenue = CASE
                            WHEN fct.ContractStatus = 'Booked'
                             AND CYpacing = 'Y' THEN 1
                            ELSE 0 END
  FROM (   SELECT base_fct.ContractNo,
                  CASE
                       WHEN base_fct.YearofBooking <= @YearofBookingminus1 THEN 'Y'
                       ELSE 'N' END AS CYpacing
             FROM (   SELECT A.DIM_CONTRACT_ID,
                             B.YearofBooking
                        FROM SchemaA.Contract A
                        JOIN SchemaB.dim_date B
                          ON SchemaB.ID BETWEEN SchemaA.StartDate AND SchemaA.EndDate) AS base_fct ) AS fct;
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Explain what the query should be doing -- or at least provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: `CROSS APPLY (VALUES...` might be very useful if your DBMS supports it. But rather unclear about how fields are "built up and calculated", needs further info

Comment: As for the example you provided you don't need nested queries at all. You can just calculate your paced revenue right from your first query where you're joining two tables. However if it's not possible in your actual query, start from using temporary tables or CTE's to increase readability.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a simple case of with statements

```
With base_fct as
(
  SELECT A.DIM_CONTRACT_ID, B.YearofBooking
  FROM SchemaA.Contract A
  JOIN SchemaB.dim_date B
  ON B.ID BETWEEN A.StartDate AND A.EndDate
),fct as 
(
    SELECT ContractNo
    ,CASE WHEN YearofBooking <= @YearofBookingminus1 THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N' END AS CYpacing
    FROM base_fct
)
select ContractNo,
,CASE WHEN ContractStatus = 'Booked' AND CYpacing = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Paced_revenue
from fct
```

By syntax, you are likely in postgresql or mssql so this should work but you should update to make the question clearer